# In python, how can you determine the values of variables in a local scope

Tags: python

For debugging purposes, I have found that it could be beneficial if I could print the variables that are in local scope and only those in local scope.

Sample:

```
def showAuthUser(self):
    """Make a request to the campfire server. 

    Returns a getPage object which is deferred.
    """
    u = self.uri + self._resource['showAuthUser']
    m = 'GET'
    n = self.username
    p = self.password
    b = base64.encodestring('{0}:{1}'.format(n, p)) 
    h = {'Authorization': 'Basic ' + b.strip()}
    return self._getPage(u, m, h)
```

Is there a way to find the values of all the variables that are in local scope after h?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use the `locals()` function